# Get property by variable name

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to render a table using emberjs templates. The table should resolve the columns to be rendered dynamically:

```
<table>
    {{#each item in this.items}}
        <tr>
            {{#each colName in this.columnNames}}
                <td>{{item.[colName]}}</td>
            {{/each}}
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

However, I think handlebars tries to access the property `colName` of an item. How can I access the property dynamically?

Comment: 'this' is the current context, so, as you said, it is an item. However you can change the scope in the template with 'with', here is the link: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/changing-scope/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: As Visualize pointed out in the comments, there is now a [native `get` helper](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get). You should prefer that over the implementation below (which may not update properly with newer versions of Ember.)

---

I'm not sure if Handlebars is able to dynamically resolve a variable like that (at least out of the box). I would probably write my own helper.

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('getProperty', function(object, property, options) {
    return Ember.get(object, property);
});
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#each item in items}}
    <tr>
    {{#each colName in columnNames}}
        <td>{{getProperty item colName}}</td>
    {{/each}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

And if my understanding of Ember bindings is correct, the helper should re-render any time `item` or `colName` is changed.

Comment: Bindings are not taken into account with this method so the value that you're fetching does not get updated when it changes. As of Ember 2.1.0 you can use the native 'get' helper in your template which takes care of this. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get

Answer (score 0):

```
{{#each item in items}}
<tr>
{{#each colName in columnNames}}
    <td>{{get item colName}}</td>
{{/each}}
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Using `get` helper.
Thank you.